# How to create a socket on client side to web server from its hostname and Port number in C#?

Tags: c#, http

I want to create a client socket to a web server knowing its hostname and port. I am asking this question from java background where you can simply write something like this

```
       Socket MyClient;
       try 
       {
            MyClient = new Socket("Hostname", PortNumber);
       }
      catch (IOException e) 
       {
            System.out.println(e);
       }
```

Is there a similar way to write that in C# ?

Comment: Will the socket you open be communicating using HTTP? Have you looked at the HttpWebClient class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx

Comment: Yeah the socket will use HTTP communication!

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel if you plan to use the socket for HTTP communication. You can use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class to do the dirty work for you.

Answer (score 0):

here sample for you.

```
   private string getHTTP(string url)
    {
        TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient();
        NetworkStream networkStream = null;
        long port = 7777;
        try
        {
            try
            {

                clientSocket.Connect(url,port );
            }
            catch { MessageBox.Show("Server is not Working", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning); return "Server is not working"; }
            byte[] sendbyte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(url);

            networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            networkStream.Write(sendbyte, 0, sendbyte.Length);
            networkStream.Flush();
        }
        catch { MessageBox.Show("Streaming Error", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning); return "Error"; }
        // receive Message from DNS Server
        byte[] receivedata = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
        networkStream.Read(receivedata, 0, clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);

        string urlnew = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedata);

        return urlnew;
    }
```

More you should reference [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx)

Comment: They plan to use the socket for HTTP communication so manually managing the socket is unnecessary.

Comment: I would want to get socket so that i can use it for other purposes. This is what i think could do the job though it is not complete: TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
Socket s = client.Client;
s.Connect(url,port);//This of course does not exist

Comment: @Xris - So you'd rather have to deal with the nitty gritty details of HTTP in order to save a couple CPU cycles instantiating the tool in .NET for solving your problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the answers provided an idea jumped out of my mind , this is what i think could be the simple answer:

```
    public Socket getSocket1(string Hostname, int PortNmber)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(Hostname, PortNumber);
        return client.Client;
    }
```